# ios navigation buttons

Tags: ios, navigation, uibutton

I'm doing a custom nav in ios for the first time. I have six buttons laid out in a row. When I tap the button, I want the image to change. However, the button is not *togglable*. The only way a button can be unselected is if another button is touched. Only one button can be active at any given time.

My idea:

- use `UIButtons`
- change UIButton image on touch
- keep track of the *active* button inside the navigation class
- when an *inactive* button is touched, make the currently active button inactive and turn the touched button to *active*

I want the end product to work like a custom `TabBarController`, but without switching layouts. I just want to edit the content in the current `ViewController`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yep, either what Nick says or what you describe.  Some might attempt to bully you into using UISegmentedControl (which is to my knowledge the only "radio button" scheme available), but there are definite flexibility advantages in "rolling your own".  (But note that you can probably make use of the `selected` state to represent "active" and handle the image change.)

Comment: Except that he stated that he didn't want the selected button to be toggle-able, so he would need to disable it anyway, in which case he may as well just make the disabled state be the down state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup the `UIButtons` in the *Interface Builder* like so:

- Default with unselected background image
- Disabled with selected background image

On touch, a button is `self.enabled = NO` which makes the `UIButtons` look change. However, the button goes dim, so I also implemented `self. adjustsImageWhenDisabled = NO`.

This way a button *can't* be re-selected once it's "active".

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the UISegmentedControl, which has that functionality already. If you need to significantly customise the look and feel though, your UIButton solution sounds fine.

Comment: `UISegmentedControl` certainly is the *correct* functionality. However, in one case I'm dealing with a column of items (vertical). I'm wondering if I should try an extension of the class you mentioned, or just go custom. Thoughts?

Comment: You could rotate it 90º using the transform property by saying view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2), but then the text will all be vertical as well, so unless you're just using icons, individual buttons are still probably your best bet.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for your help Nick!